# macOS network upload being throttled?

Tags: networking, macos, mac

Short story, we have had 3 techs and then an entire crew from our cable internet provider to verify our internet speeds on ethernet. The choke point in upload speed is our computer. They have tested every point along the line and the slow down only happens on our iMac and Mac Pro desktop. They are running different macOS versions (High Sierra and Mojave). The line says 30mbps up and the computers can only do 3-5mbps up.

How could the computer be throttling?

Comment: I find Macs to be very reliable at maximizing network performance, so I doubt your Macs are throttling their own upload speeds. How are you testing? Do you get better speeds when you switch to Wi-Fi? What speed do you get with iperf between the two Macs via your Ethernet LAN? macOS has a built-in throttling facility called DummyNet that's off by default and a hassle to turn on. Did you ever mess with it? Or with ipfw or pf? Or with the Network Link Conditioner (it's like a GUI for DummyNet) system preference panel you can get from developer.apple.com?

Comment: Hello, we havent messed with any systems pref, on wifi same limit to upload at 5-7mbts/sec with reduced download from 1000 to 500. The issue is the upload for some reason just wont go above the 5 up. The cable company was in here and attached their reader directly to my ethernet cable and the got 35 up. So in their minds the limit is the computer.

Comment: Does the same slowdown apply to local transfers (Mac -> Mac and/or Mac -> local PC)? Does your ISP provide IPv6, and if so does it matter if the connections are over IPv4 or IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

Fist inpect the network connections using the activity monitor utility. Also if you are on a wireless network, you may need to delete then re add the network. You may be connected to the 2.4 Ghz network instead of 5 GHz. Also, if the CPU on either computer is already being stressed, it will result in much slower speeds. Use this test for more accurate metrics.

https://www.measurementlab.net/tests/ndt/

Comment: We are on a wired connection, and then we have gone to the 5GHz only to test for differences. the download drops as expected but the upload remains the same. We also took the same computer to my home and it had no issues with the upload speed, everything was fast at 30-50 upload. So I say its not my computer.... the cable company uses some testing device on my ethernet cable and they get the full upload speed, but when i plug in my computer, back to 5.

Comment: Is the computer using dhcp or is it assigned a static IP? Try booting it in recovery mode and then running the speed test https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/28/how-to-launch-safari-in-os-x-recovery-mode/

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? If you dont mind, please vote on my answer, Im new and have no rep lol